# Programmatic p:menu executes actionexpression more and more often

Tags: jsf, dynamic, menu, primefaces

I have a bean which has a list of items and which creates a menu-model once:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ItemController implements Serializable{

    private List<Item> items; //list of items (String, id)
    private MenuModel model;

    public void loadMenu(){
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();
        ELContext elCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
        ExpressionFactory expFact = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

        Submenu submenu = new Submenu();
        submenu.setLabel("Your items:");
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.setId("lm" + items.get(i).getId());
            item.setValue(items.get(i).getName());
            item.setAjax(false); //sonst setupdate setzen!
            item.setActionExpression(expFact.createMethodExpression(elCtx, "#{itemController.loadItem("+items.get(i).getId()+")}", Void.class, new Class[]{Integer.class}));
            submenu.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        model.addSubmenu(submenu);
    }
    public void loadItem(int id){
        System.out.println("EXECUTED: " + id);
    }
    // ...getters and setters here...
}
```

But each time I click on a menu-item, the "loadItem(int id)" method is executed one time more often than the last time clicked.

For example, the logger prints:

- on first click:  "EXECUTED 1"
- on second click (same menu item): "EXECUTED 1" "EXECUTED 1"
- on third click (same menu item): "EXECUTED 1" "EXECUTED 1" "EXECUTED 1"
- and so on

When I let the page reload the URL, it resets and starts over again. Refresh doen't change anything, when I create the same menu manually, it works perfectly. Is it a bug?

Can anyone help? I have no clue what makes the menu item act like this.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest?

Comment: Hi, i am using JSF 2.0; Apache MyFaces API 2.0.2

Comment: That's the spec version. I was asking which JSF impl (Mojarra or MyFaces) and its version (Mojarra is currently at 2.1.22 and MyFaces is currently at 2.1.12). Edit: Okay, it's thus MyFaces 2.0.2. That's extremely ancient (more than 3.5 years old). Try the latest version to exclude the behavior being just caused by some bug of MyFaces which is already fixed for long.